# Generate Enums from Database or Vice Versa?

Tags: c#, enums, t4

I'm trying to figure out which is the the "correct" way to do this.  I have a bunch of lookup tables in my database and would like to place an enum on top of those values so, when coding, it's easier to read (as well as not use hard-coded values).

I'm wondering if I should generate my table values based on an existing enumeration or if I should generate my enumeration from my table's values.

**EDIT**

*Based on the first couple of comments, here are some clarifications:*

Frequency of changes to the values could be rather frequent as they are intended to be rather dynamic.  That being said, a compile will be necessary before adding any of these either way, because the enumeration needs to be updated to expose the new values.

The main reason for this need is because we don't want to tie people down to a specific list of values, we would like the applications to have the ability to add new entries as and when they need to.

In the past, we have generated the data from enumerations, but I'm second guessing myself

Comment: what is your current practice?

Comment: Either way is not maintainance friendly.

Comment: how frequently will the contents of these lookup tables change?

Comment: I always believe in "the code comes first".
If something need to be introduced in the code, is the DB that must reflect the code, not viceversa, but this is a personal belief and it depends.

Comment: We code gen enumerations based on DB tables using nvelocity and not the other way around because of FK constraints. Before we would have to manually maintain them in code (ugh) so code gen lets us do fun coding instead of typing practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We usually generate enums from the database. We use [CodeSmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com/), which allows us to create project files that can easily regenerate the enums as needed.

We've gone the other way occasionally, usually for reporting purposes (when existing enum values are persisted).

And, of course, we have enums whose values are never persisted.

In general the only reason to generate enums from the database is if code needs to make decisions based on them. If you just want to populate a ComboBox and persist the user's choice, don't generate an enum.

Obviously making decisions based on enums (or strings) whose values can change is fragile. You may want to consider including expiration dates (or "from" and "through" dates) in your database schema, so that existing values are not deleted. Filter expired values when populating UI selectors. This also makes it easier to have referential integrity.

As always in C#, you have to be aware that enum values may fall outside of the expected range. Include a `default` on your `switch`.

We came up with helper classes for creating cached lookup lists that make these easier to use.

I'm not advocating going down this route. If you have to, this is how we did it.

Answer (score 0):

There's also a third option in that you have a explicit model which describes the schema in the level of detail you require and then you generate both data & schema from that model.

Regarding your question I think what you should do is thinking about the problem in your context and list pros/cons for you with each alternative and decide on what makes most sense for you and your business.

I have worked worked with all three strategies for different applications, the one I personally prefer is having an explicit model buts depending on the context.

Sorry for being fuzzy but I think for these kind of questions there's real golden rule which always applies in all cases.